# Best practice for iterating over fastutil primitive ArrayLists, e.g. IntArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, hpc, fastutil

What's best for read-iterating over an `IntArrayList` from the [fastutil library](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) in Java?

fastutil is a library that is used for increased performance above what the standard library's  collection classes and algorithms can do. So "best" in this context means best performance.

I've followed the [advice in the fastutil docs](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/) and set my IDE (Eclipse) to warn when boxing happens:
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Potential Programming Problems -> Boxing and unboxing conversions -> set to Warning
However, Eclipse seems to omit some warnings. See below in the code for details.

I came across these alternatives so far for iterating:

```
IntArrayList list = ...;

// 1. for-loop-with-index-variable
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // do something with list.getInt(i)
}

// 2. for-each-loop-with-wrapped
Integer value = list.getInt(0); // Eclipse correctly warns in this line
for (Integer element : list) { // autoboxing happens here somewhere, but Eclipse does NOT warn
    // do something with element
}

// 3. for-each-loop-with-primitive
for (int element : list) { // Eclipse does NOT warn. Does autoboxing happen here?
    // do something with element
}

// 4. forEach-method-with-consumer
list.forEach((int element) -> {
    // do something with element
});

// 5. for-loop-with-IntIterator
for (IntIterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    // do something with iter.nextInt()
}
```

Comment: If you want to write the perfect answer, feel encouraged to also include details about write-iterating over such a list. I will accept the best answer in a few days.

Comment: Yes, I can do the benchmarks myself. And I will if nobody else is interested.

Comment: From an educated guess, the fastest is very likely #1, followed by #5. #4 could beat #1 and #5 if there is some parallelism involved, which is not guaranteed. #2 and #3 definitely autobox and are the usual losers in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing definitely occurs in #2 and #3 cases. I think #1 or #5 would be most optimal in terms of performance.

Taken from the Fastutil documentation https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/index.html:

> Note that the “for each” style of iteration can hide boxing and unboxing: even if you iterate using a primitive variable (as in for(long x: s), where s is a LongSet), the actual iterator used will be object-based, as Java knows nothing about fastutil's type-specific next()/previous() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely #1. :)

[And I have to add more character of StackOverflow won't let me post this.]

Comment: Well, except that it would be better to cache list.size() in a local variable.